# How to change status bar icons color in IOS version under 13 - Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i just can't change the status bar icons color in IOS version under 13 of my Xamarin Forms App. I do this already and works great with IOS version above 13. I could change the background color but i don't need it, i need the icons itself.

Look at the example:
This code just works to change the status bar BackgroundColor, i set the status.TintColor but it does not changes...

```
private void ChangeStatusBar()
    {
        UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
        if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
        {
            statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            statusBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
        }
    }
```

I use this to change the status bar icons color in IOS version above 13 and works ok:

```
 UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(isLightTheme ? UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent : UIStatusBarStyle.DarkContent, false);
            GetCurrentViewController().SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you had added the key-value description in info.plist

`View controller-based status bar appearance` as **No** (the default value is Yes).

[image]

Comment: Did you want to set the color of status bar as white ?

Comment: Yes. I want to set the icons to white

Comment: Could you provide the effect on iOS13 ?